# how to pull TesorFlow into docker windows container?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I installed docker and tested with hello-world just to make sure its fine. Docker is set to Windows Containers. Then I used the following :

```
docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

Got error :

```
C:\Users\pubud>docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any help?

I am following this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8IE46prExtQYjlld1RSOHk2Ukk/view) for setup. I am using Docker for Windows since I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to add `gcr.io/`. just add `tensorflow/tensorflow` to your docker run command.

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow
```

[image: Screenshot]
[image: SCreenshot2]

Comment: This is what I got >>>>  C:\Users\pubud>docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow
Unable to find image 'tensorflow/tensorflow:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from tensorflow/tensorflow
docker: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: it worked for me. Can you do `docker system prune -a` ( Be conscious before doing this it delete all unused images/containers and volumes) to refresh docker on your system